# Injected service is undefined when testing using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, service, karma-jasmine

For some reason when I run the test Jasmine is telling me that 'DataFactory' is undefined. Any ideas why?

```
describe('Practice', function(){
beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
var ctrl;
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, DataFactory){
    spyOn(DataFactory, 'getArtists').andCallThrough();
    ctrl = $controller('ArtistCtrl')   
}));

it('should have array available on load', function(){
    expect(DataFactory.getArtists).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(DataFactory.getArtists.callCount).toEqual(1);
});
```

});

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory('DataFactory', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        getArtists: function(){
            return $http.get('artists.json');   
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For support you have to show the code where you define the DataFactory!

Here I see another typo:

```
expect(DataFactory.getArtists).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(dataFactory.getArtists.callCount).toEqual(1); <-- DataFactory instead of dataFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define DataFactory in your test.

Do this.

```
describe('Practice', function(){
 var ctrl;
 var DataFactory;

 beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
 beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _DataFactory_){
    DataFactory = _DataFactory_;
    spyOn(DataFactory, 'getArtists').andCallThrough();
    ctrl = $controller('ArtistCtrl', {
      DataFactory: DataFactory
    });   
}));

it('should have array available on load', function(){
    expect(DataFactory.getArtists).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(DataFactory.getArtists.callCount).toEqual(1);
});
```